# How can I remove the mysterious padding in Mac SwiftUI using NavigationTitle?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

How can I remove the mysterious padding in Mac SwiftUI using NavigationTitle? Due to this issue, the dividing line between views shifts vertically, causing layout distortions. If you copy and paste the following code, it will work similarly on a Mac. Thank you in advance.

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationSplitView {
                Text("1")
            } content: {
                Text("2")
                    .navigationTitle("")
                    .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 200, ideal: 400)


                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem {
                            Text("← what is this extra space")
                        }
                    }

            } detail: {
                Text("3")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem {
                            Text("Tools")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HtTT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyIJR.png

Answer (score 0):

The space that you're seeing is from the title that *would* be there if you did not define a blank string.

In SwiftUI's implementation of the `NSWindow` hosting your view, that space is reserved for an `NSToolbarTitleView` whose bounds are constrained by dimensions of the `NSSplitView` in your `NavigationSplitView`.

Of which I am aware — at the time of this answer and not considering any SwiftUI updates in macOS Sonoma — there is no exposure in SwiftUI itself to remove `NSToolbarTitleView` or reduce its size. However, you *can* do this by accessing the `NSWindow` instance, traversing its view hierarchy, and applying adjustments on each layout-affecting `NSView`. There is a catch to consider though...

For reasons I don't understand, Apple seems to be making use of `Combine` publishers or some other async utility to bridge the connection between changes made in SwiftUI and updates which should draw in AppKit. This is rather strange, because when you see the X offset of a toolbar item updated synchronously with the resizing of split view bounds, this would typically be handled by an `NSLayoutConstraint.`

It's difficult to explain why I think this is what's happening without first presenting the workaround/solution, so let's start there:

```swift
import SwiftUI;
import Combine;

@main
struct ExampleApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .background(WindowAccessor())
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Main Content

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            NavigationSplitView {
                Text("1")
            } content: {
                Text("2")
                    .navigationTitle("")
                    .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 200, ideal: 400)
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem {
                            Text("← what is this extra space")
                        }
                    }
                
            } detail: {
                Text("3")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItem {
                            Text("Tools")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

// MARK: - Accessor for View-hosting NSWindow

struct WindowAccessor: NSViewRepresentable {
    
    func makeNSView(context: Context) -> NSView {
        let view = NSView()
        
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            
            /// Outermost View on `NSWindow`
            guard let nsThemeFrame = view.window?.contentView?.superview else { return }
            
            /// The window's title view.
            guard let nsToolbarTitleView = nsThemeFrame.subview(
                2, /// `NSTitlebarContainerView`
                0, /// `NSTitlebarView`
                4, /// `NSToolbarView`
                4  /// `NSToolbarTitleView`
            ) else { return }
            
            /// The first toolbar item which is not the title.
            guard let nsToolbarItemViewer = nsThemeFrame.subview(
                2, /// `NSTitlebarContainerView`
                0, /// `NSTitlebarView`
                4, /// `NSToolbarView`
                1  /// `NSToolbarItemViewer`
            ) else { return }
            
            /// Store for `NSToolbarTitleView`'s frame.
            var toolbarTitleFrame = nsToolbarTitleView.frame;
            
            /// Update the frame store every time the `NSToolbarTitleView`'s
            /// frame is updated.
            ///
            nsToolbarTitleView.publisher(for: \.frame).sink(receiveValue: { rect in
                toolbarTitleFrame = rect;
            }).store(in: &NSView.subscriptions);
            
            /// Overwrite the frame origin every time `NSToolbarItemViewer`'s
            /// frame is updated.
            ///
            nsToolbarItemViewer.publisher(for: \.frame).sink(receiveValue: { _ in
                nsToolbarItemViewer.setFrameOrigin(toolbarTitleFrame.origin);
            }).store(in: &NSView.subscriptions);
            
        });
        
        return view;
    }
    
    func updateNSView(_ nsView: NSView, context: Context) { }
}

// MARK: - NSView+(Subscribers & Subview Helper)

extension NSView {
    
    static var subscriptions: [AnyCancellable] = [];
    
    /// Safely retrieve a subview from an NSView's hierarchy.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - path: The index path at which the subview should exist.
    ///   - as: Optional type to which the target subview should cast.
    /// - Returns: The subview at the target index path.
    func subview<T>(_ path: Int..., as: T.Type = NSView.self) -> T? {
        var subview: NSView = self;
        for i in path {
            if i + 1 > subview.subviews.count {
                return nil;
            }
            subview = subview.subviews[i];
        }
        
        return subview as? T;
    }
    
}
```

This workaround makes use of the window accessor "trick" to gain access to the `NSWindow` which is hosting your SwiftUI view. Through an extension on `NSView`, the `NSToolbarTitleView` and `NSToolbarItemViewer` are both acquired and a subscription to their `frame` properties is stored in `NSView.subscriptions.` As the frame for `NSToolbarTitleView` is updated, the relevant store is overwritten and, when `NSToolbarItemViewer`'s frame is subsequently updated, its origin is overwritten with the stored value for `NSToolbarTitleView`.

There are a few strange things happening here. In my own tests, I tried to simply drop the `NSLayoutConstraint`s which were affecting horizontal positioning for the `NSToolbarItemViewer`. This would offset the view as expected but, if anything happened in the SwiftUI `ContentView` which caused draw, the toolbar item would immediately snap back into its original position. Further, if I tried to update the constraints/frame on both the `NSToolbarTitleView` and the `NSToolbarItemViewer`, only the trailing change was applied.

It is that last observation which leads me to believe that `Combine` or some other asynchronous utility is at work here. That one value cannot be updated in a single draw cycle without affecting the value of the other suggests that either a subscriber is mutating the values as they change *or* that the views are re-drawing on each update entirely.

Whatever the case may be, you can modify the logic in this implementation to further offset the other views in your application. There will be a *flash of un-styled content* which occurs when using the window accessor method with `DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: )`. If you want to avoid this, another option would be swizzling the implementation of `NSView.addSubview`, and intercepting the relevant subviews there.